# Images are not showing in frontend in magento2

Tags: magento2

I have issue with my store , All the images are not showing on the frontend.

To increase speed of site,I want to optimize all images in site.
for that i have already tried 1 plugin (https://github.com/tinify/magento2-plugin)

Comment: issue is all product images are not coming in front

Comment: Look for this -> Are they visible in the back-end & they are set with the **`'base', 'small', 'thumbnail', 'swatches'`** attribute?

Comment: Did the images disappear before or after you installed the tinify plugin?

Comment: images disappear after  installing plugin .

Comment: and images are also disappear in backend